# How get and paginate with many entities in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

First, sorry for my english.

I have a problem filtering and paginate in nestjs.

I have these entities 'Contract', 'Property' and 'Person'

A Contract can have a Property and a Property can have one person

The person have an attribute (document: string)

My problem:

I can't get and paginate the contract that have a property with a person with a document like '123'.

I have this paginte:

```
async paginate(paginationOptions: IPaginationOptions, options?: any): Promise<Pagination<T>> {
        // Set maximum limit
        paginationOptions.limit = paginationOptions.limit > 50 ? 50 : paginationOptions.limit;
        return await paginate<T>(this.repository, paginationOptions, options);
    }
```

And the options can not work with

```
options = {
  where: {
    contract: {
      property: { person: '123' }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to destructure the object option like this ,{...options}

Comment: Could you add your 'Contract', 'Property' and 'Person' entities and update the question?

Comment: @SyedMohibUddin does not work :(

Comment: @ErangaHeshan this entities are general. I have the same problem with a Propietor with a Person. I can't filter by Propietor.Person.document.

In general i can't filter by Entity1.Entity2...attribute

Comment: @LucasCaballero I'm not sure about using paginate, but this is an existing issue in typeorm. Please check https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4396